Rails 7: OmniAuth Route Not Recognized alongside Devise
I'm facing an issue integrating OmniAuth independently alongside Devise in a Rails 7 app. Devise with OmniAuth for user sign-in works perfectly. However, I am trying to enable connections to other external accounts (specifically Basecamp) to fetch data via their API, not for sign-in.
I have set up an initializer for OmniAuth as follows:
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :basecamp, Rails.application.credentials.omniauth.basecamp[:public_key], Rails.application.credentials.omniauth.basecamp[:private_key]
end

After restarting the server, when I navigate to /auth/basecamp, I encounter a routing error: "No route matches [GET] '/auth/basecamp'". This error persists whether I try POST or GET.
Here’s a snippet of my middleware stack:
$ rails middleware
use Rack::Sendfile
use ActionDispatch::Static
use ActionDispatch::Executor
use ActionDispatch::ServerTiming
use ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware
use Rack::Runtime
use Rack::MethodOverride
use ActionDispatch::RequestId
use ActionDispatch::RemoteIp
use Sprockets::Rails::QuietAssets
use Rails::Rack::Logger
use ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions
use WebConsole::Middleware
use ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions
use ActionDispatch::ActionableExceptions
use ActionDispatch::Reloader
use ActionDispatch::Callbacks
use ActiveRecord::Migration::CheckPending
use ActionDispatch::Cookies
use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
use ActionDispatch::Flash
use ActionDispatch::ContentSecurityPolicy::Middleware
use ActionDispatch::PermissionsPolicy::Middleware
use Rack::Head
use Rack::ConditionalGet
use Rack::ETag
use Rack::TempfileReaper
use Warden::Manager
use OmniAuth::Builder
use OmniAuth::Strategies::Heroku
use Jumpstart::AccountMiddleware
run JumpstartApp::Application.routes

It appears OmniAuth::Builder is loaded, but it seems non-responsive to /auth/basecamp. Devise is configured in the application but not using Basecamp as a provider.
Could Devise be interfering even if it's not configured to handle Basecamp? Any insights or suggestions would be appreciated!

"However, I am trying to enable connections to other external accounts (specifically Basecamp) to fetch data via their API, not for sign-in." there are other gems for that. OmniAuth really just does authentication and one API call to fetch data post auth.

Thanks for the comment. You’re right but in this case, all I need is the token and the refreshing. Everything else, I’m doing myself and for that, OmniAuth is perfect.
